# ClassNotFoundException specifically when casting

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nio

I'm very new to android and trying to get a mariadb table into my app using a socket. This requires me to cast the ObjectInputStream to my POJO, which throws a ClassNotFoundException error. The error seems to be tied specifically to the cast, because the POJO and app work fine otherwise. For example, I have no issue creating a new VizObject in my onCreate method, and adding it to an ArrayList of VizObjects. It's specifically the (ArrayList) cast that makes Android Studio very unhappy.

All the suggestions I've found on Google either seem to be for Eclipse, not applicable to modern Android Studio, or just not applicable to my specific problem (having over 64k methods). Invalidated cache, cleaned project, rebuilt project, nothing I've tried resolves the issue outside of commenting out the line with the cast.

Besides a fix, also open to suggestions on going a wholly different route than my current socket implementation.

```
    @Override
public DatabaseObject loadInBackground() {
    try {
        AsynchronousSocketChannel client = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
        Future<Void> future = client.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.2", 7777));
        future.get();

        InputStream inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(client);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        ArrayList<VizObject> results = (ArrayList<VizObject>) objectInputStream.readObject();
        return new DatabaseObject(results, "");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DatabaseLoaderTask", "loadInBackground", e);
    }
    return null;
}



java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: VizObject
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:682)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1703)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1594)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1872)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1412)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1066)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2013)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1899)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1412)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
    at xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2.DatabaseLoaderTask.loadInBackground(DatabaseLoaderTask.java:32)
    at xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2.DatabaseLoaderTask.loadInBackground(DatabaseLoaderTask.java:14)
    at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:307)
    at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:60)
    at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:48)
    at androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:141)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "VizObject" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~nwS0dBCfILG9tbh8Sb84Rg==/xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2-kpBRtYVLeb3kBoLwnMBSqw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~nwS0dBCfILG9tbh8Sb84Rg==/xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2-kpBRtYVLeb3kBoLwnMBSqw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:682) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1703) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1594) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1872) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1412) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427) 
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1066) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2013) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1899) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1412) 
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427) 
    at xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2.DatabaseLoaderTask.loadInBackground(DatabaseLoaderTask.java:32) 
    at xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2.DatabaseLoaderTask.loadInBackground(DatabaseLoaderTask.java:14) 
    at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:307) 
    at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:60) 
    at androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:48) 
    at androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:141) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "VizObject" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex", zip file "/data/app/~~nwS0dBCfILG9tbh8Sb84Rg==/xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2-kpBRtYVLeb3kBoLwnMBSqw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~nwS0dBCfILG9tbh8Sb84Rg==/xyz.matthewsavage.vizreader_2-kpBRtYVLeb3kBoLwnMBSqw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system_ext/lib]]
```

Comment: `or just not applicable to my specific problem (having over 64k methods).` have you tried doing the suggested fix for this ? it's probably suggesting to enable multidex, right ? worth a try perhaps

Comment: @a_local_nobody I did not, only because I read it was unnecessary if the minSdkVersion is => 21, mine is 30. Also I have, like, 15 methods. The very first thing I tried to do with the project was this socket thing, it's going poorly. I'll give it a try regardless, thanks for taking the time to post a suggestion =)

Comment: yeah, i'm not sure what this error is, i don't have experience working with sockets but seems interesting that the error says that it can't find the class, if anything i thought it would give a cast exception, is there no way your socket can send you data as Json strings ? you can then use gson to convert it to avoid this

Comment: also, you have to be sure that this code is synchronous, irrelevant to your question but after you resolve this, you might realize that the method still returns null if the execution isn't synchronous

Comment: any chance you're trying to cast to an ArrayList rather than VizObject[] array and thats causing the problem?

Comment: You seem to be serializing `VizObject`s over a network, yes? I assume that means you have two applications: the one sending the data (some sort of server), and the one receiving the data (your Android app). Make sure you're using the same `VizObject` class on both ends.

Comment: That said, it may be better to stop using Java serialization and look for a different approach. For example, you could serialize your objects to JSON or XML, send that over the network, and then parse the JSON/XML back into Java objects. There are libraries out there that can handle automagically mapping POJOs to JSON/XML and vice versa.

Comment: @Slaw Yes, what you think I'm doing is exactly what I'm doing, and yeah, definitely same object-I just copy/pasted the VizObject class from my java project to my android project. Anyways, I'll take your advice and use JSON instead. I was just so happy with how easily this worked between two java programs and was hopeful that ease would carry over to android =/.